# Explanation on Member Detection code

Tags: c++

It's  not the concept as a whole, but rather one of the methods it uses to determine if a class has an `n` data-member. Here is the full code; an ordinary use of SFINAE for member detection.

```
template <typename T>
struct has_X {
    struct Fallback { int X; };
    struct Derived : T, Fallback {};

    template <typename U, U> struct S;

    template <typename C> static char (&f(S<int Fallback::*, &C::X> *))[1];
    template <typename C> static char (&f(...))[2];

    public:
        const static bool value = sizeof(f<Derived>(0)) == 2;
};
```

The part where `Derived` inherits from both `Fallback` and `T` confuses me because when we do the overload of `f`, `&C::X` is `&Derived::X`. But shouldn't this overload always be chosen because isn't `Derived` guaranteed to have `X` since it inherits from `Fallback` which has that data-member?

Maybe I'm overlooking something. However, this single piece of code has shown and taught me things I never knew, so maybe there *is* something to this. What I would expect is for that overload to always be chosen (not the one with the `...`) because `Derived` should always have `X` since it inherits from `Fallback`. But this is not the case. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Did you mean `S<int Fallback::*, &C::X>`?

Comment: @NateKohl Yeah sorry I wrote this from memory...

Comment: BTW it looks like you reversed the logic (`value` will be `true` if `T` does *not* have `X`). Either compare with 1 or switch the return types of `f` around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fallback` has one data member named `X`, but Derived will have *two* if `T` also has a member named `X`, in which case `Derived::X` cannot be taken unambiguously. So if `T` does not have `X`, the first overload is used, and if `T` has `X`, the second more general version is used. This is why you can tell these cases apart depending on the size of their return types.

Comment: Don't you mean ambiguously and not unambiguously?

Comment: @David, no - if `T` has a member named `X` then `Derived::X` can *not* be taken *un*ambiguously, i.e. `Derived::X` is ambiguous. Sorry about the double negation ;)

Comment: Okay, great answer by the way. :)